# DB design : Config Data, Actual Data, Log Data

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design, data-structures, data-modeling

I want to know if there is any typical approach to differenciate this kind of data

I have to listing devices (for example) in a db, ane everyone will have

- Configuration data
- Actual data
- Log data

*I commonly mix Config/Actual Data in the same table and another table for Log data*,

This seems to be an usual issue, so I wonder if there is any standar way to do it.

**EDIT:**:

Here an Example

*A semaphore at the street :*

- **Config data** = position (street intersection), type (for passengers,
  cars), etc..
- **Actual data** = colorstate=red, green, walk, stop.. functionality=ok, being repaired, etc..
- **Log data** = date/time + colorstate + (any other of the Actual data needed to be logged)

Thanks

Comment: Knowing a little more about the data would make it easier to apply some relational theory. Remember also the saying, the column must depend on the key, the whole key and nothing but the key.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction between your actual data and your log data.

Comment: @Catcall log data are date-info pair, for example every log record could consist of a snapshot of the actual data, in the example, colorstate is the color NOW, but in log data records store date related events, for example what colorstate it was in a specific past date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might divide it up like so (being lazy about sql syntax and types):

`

### signal_config

id (key)
position 
type

### signal_log

signal_id, timestamp (compound key)
color_stat one of (red, yellow, green)
functioning_state 
`

To my mind, there's stuff that doesn't change about the signal, like it's location and type, and stuff that does change like its repair state and color. With this table you could query for the times on a particular day that the light was both working and red.

Comment: That's exactly my approach, I wonder if there is some standar or theoretical modus operandi for such cases

Comment: position depends on id only: if the id changes, position does. If the time changes, position doesn't. Signal state and functioning_state change with time, so that table requires both signal_id and timestamp. The theoretical modus operandi is relatinal database normalization. E.F.Codd wrote the first paper on it, and "the data should depend on the key, the whole key and nothing but the key" ends with "So help me Codd." ;-) It's worth mentioning because as you read through the normal forms you'll see how that phrase summarizes them.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Comment: I've finally decided that "actual" data, don't even need to be in database, with config and log, is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a bit of confusion over terminology here.

What you're calling "config data" sounds to me like "business key" or "candidate key": a set of data which is (probably) unchanging and which uniquely identifies the entity: there is only one traffic light at the end of Main Street.

What you're calling "actual data" seems like the attributes of an entity, which change over time.

So I don't think there is a design problem putting them in the same table.

Also it is a very good idea to record "log data" (audit trail, history) in a separate table.

Comment: Hello, you are right in the classification: ConfigData=rarely change, ActualData= usually change, LogData =does change but is history, reference of others, and grow, it's good to be in other table, about the first two, are you saying that rate of change is a reason to put it in a different table? regards

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you would benefit from properly normalizing this information into several tables.

it does not look like you should consider jamming it all into one table.

Comment: Why? I mean, Log seems ok to be put separatedly, but Config and Actual data share same ID, I found no reason to put them in separate tables, but perhaps I am missing something..

Answer (score 0):

Your config and actual should go into different tables. The config seems to be rather static and when written to a table experiencing very few writes will not fragment and degrade performance over time.  The actual data table would be smaller and could then be optimized for the relation back to the config using indexes, partitioning, pad index, etc.  The actual table may fragment more often but should be able to be rebuilt quickly because it contains less data.

Optimize the log table in a way which benefits your prevelant search method.  If you search by date range on most occasions cluster the table by logged date.  If the search is by an id of a config item consider partitioning or just cluster by the id and permit the table to fragment, and leave it fragmented based on the id of the config item.